# Multiples SELECT in MySql

Tags: mysql

I try to multiple select in MySql but it doesn't work.

Example :

```
SELECT (SELECT column1, column2 FROM table1 WHERE column3='something') AS query1,
(SELECT column4 FROM table1 WHERE column4='something') AS query2
```

And the result i try to have is something similar to this :

```
[{query1}, {query2 : [...]}]
```

query1 always will have only 1 row but query2 can will have multiple row

Can someone help me please ?

Comment: Why would you need to combine them this way? Why not just run each query individually?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this way:
WITH query 1 AS (Select .....),
query 2 AS (select ...),
query3 AS ( SELECT * FROM query 1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM query 2)

SELECT * FROM query3

Comment: Thanks but that's not it

Comment: So what else do you need?

Comment: Nothing, thank you, I had to do otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean ? Join column wise?

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM table1;
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|       1 | XYZ     | ABC     |     255 |
|       2 | YZEX    | AVF     |     567 |
|       3 | AGH     | TYRE    |    5467 |
|       4 | ZXS     | KJA     |     456 |
|       5 | AAA     | FRES    |      56 |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

And CTE to combine columns:

```
with cte1 AS (SELECT column1, column2 FROM table1 WHERE column3='ABC'), 
cte2 AS (SELECT column4 FROM table1 WHERE column4=567)
SELECT * FROM cte1 JOIN cte2;

+---------+---------+---------+
| column1 | column2 | column4 |
+---------+---------+---------+
|       1 | XYZ     |     567 |
+---------+---------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: hello, no that's not it, I had to do it differently, it doesn't matter, thank you for your help!